# attach mixin to model when it is created based on a field?

Tags: django, django-models

Can I attach a Mixin automatically to a Model when it is created based on a field?

I have been looking at the 3 options of Model inheritance https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance but I am not sure how to achieve what I am looking to do and if it is possible.

I just want ONE table where I will store all the fields, no matter if one field is just for 
one of the type.
This table will have a type field.

```
class Example(models.Model):

    objects = ExampleManager()

    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    # All the fields needed for all the types, the common and specific fields

    type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=('T1','T2'))
```

Now, when I do:

```
all = Example.objects.all()

for a in all:
  a.quack()
```

I would like that `quack` is different according to the `type` field.

But I would like to avoid to write a quack function in the `Example` class model with several if.
I would like to encapsulate into classes the logic for each subtype.

Can I attach a Mixin automatically to the Model when it is created based on the `type` field?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by defining a field subclass with a `contribute_to_class` method. That's how fields with the `choices` attribute define a `get_FOO_display` method on their models.

`contribute_to_class` is passed the model class, and the name this field is being defined as. You can use the model class to add extra methods. It might work something like this:

```
class DuckField(models.CharField):

    def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name):
        super(DuckField, self).contribute_to_class(cls, name)

        # method to be added
        def quack(self):
            return '%s quacks!' % self

        # add it to the model
        cls.quack = quack
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did not expect something at the Field level, I'm not sure to see how that works. So I should define a new field that will be my type field? type = DuckField() ? and where do I define the logic for different types? I need some if...else statements in the contribute_to_class model to define several quack methods for each type?

Comment: Yes, you would use it just like any other field. This was just a simple example, but I don't really know how you intend to use it: depending on your use case, you could have multiple methods and determine which of them to apply to the model depending on some attribute; or, you could define multiple field classes and use whichever one you want.

Comment: But you actually have the class passed to contribute_to_class, it is not the model object right? So I cannot access to the value of the fields of the returned object?